# Is there a way to test WCF Data Services (OData) using SoapUI?

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, soapui

I would like to be able to run some SoapUI tests against my OData service.

SoapUI supports rest, and I know at the core, OData is like a rest service.  But I am unable to get SoapUI to work with OData.

I have looked at some rest tutorials, but they don't seem to fit the OData model.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to load one of my services into it so that I could view responses and mess with the request headers. Using SoapUI 4.0.0 I just checked the Add REST Service option on the new project window and left the initial WSDL/WADL box empty. Follow the prompts from there and it should work.

To navigate it, I just changed the service endpoint.

Comment: Just to be clear, the service you added in was an OData (WCF Data Service) right?  Not a normal WCF Service?  If so, how did you get it to deal with the single quotes for filters?

Comment: Yeah it is an Odata(WCF Data Service). I was able to define a filter parameter named $filter and use Name eq 'Test' as the value to get it to return the filtered result. Is the issue with the single quotes around the value or a single quote inside of the string?